# Relay coil inductance variations vs. temperature

Tags: relay, inductor, temperature, inductance, coil

How does relay (something like this https://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/datasheets/songle-12v-relay.pdf) coil inductance changes with increasing/decreasing temperature? And how can we calculate the new value of coil?

Comment: In the linked datasheet there is no mention about inductance of the coil.

Comment: Are you not more interested in the difference in the open and close inductance of the electro-mechanical relay? That dwarfs any temperature variations.

Comment: Thank you @Oldfart for the comment, why does it dwarf T variations?

Comment: Because there is normally a piece of external metal that gets attracted to the metal core in the coil. When the metal parts connect (or even move closer), your magnetic field and thus inductance change. Think of it as switching between two different sizes of metal cores.

Comment: @Oldfart It is obvious that why inductance changes, It is not obvious that why as you said, that dwarfs any temperature variations?

Comment: As Reroute explained: the inductance barely changes with temperature. Switching will change the size of the metal core with a few percentage. To me that warrants the term "dwarfed". (Although now I think about it, I have never before thought what the change of a metal coil core because it expands due to temperature does. )

Answer (score 3):

The inductance barely changes with temperature, as this is defined by the coils geometry, e.g. its dimensions and number of turns, you can think of it as the diameter and length of the coil will increase slightly, this changes the flux density at the ends of the coils slightly,

the core material can shift slightly in relative permittivity, however both of these effects are below what most people are capable of measuring at home,

The biggest change will come in the coil resistance increasing as temperature goes up, this is because coppers resistance per length increases with temperature, this changes the actuation and hold voltages slightly as you need a slightly higher voltage to get the same current through a higher resistance.